# The entity or complex type 'MedPModel.Customer' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I get the error mentioned in the subject when I convert the wms_SOHeaderResults to a list. Any idea on how to resolve it?

```
 var wms_SOHeaderResults = from soh in _mpiContext.SalesOrders.AsNoTracking()
        join cu in _mpiContext.Customers.AsNoTracking() on soh.CustomerId equals cu.CustomerId into group_soh_cu
        join cs in _mpiContext.CarrierServices on soh.CarrierServiceId equals cs.ServiceId into group_soh_cs
        orderby soh.OrderedOnDate descending
        from cu in group_soh_cu.DefaultIfEmpty(new Customer() { CustomerId = soh.CustomerId, CustomerName = default(string) })
        from cs in group_soh_cs.DefaultIfEmpty(new Data.CarrierService() { ServiceId = soh.CarrierServiceId ?? default(Guid), ServiceName = default(string) })
        where soh.OrderedOnDate > so_CutOff
        select new WMS_SOHeaderVM
        {
            SalesOrderId = soh.SalesOrderId,
            SalesOrderNumber = soh.SalesOrderNumber,
            OrderedOnDate = soh.OrderedOnDate,
            PromisedByDate = soh.PromisedByDate,
            PickOnDate = soh.PickOnDate,
            LateAfterDate = soh.LateAfterDate,
            CarrierServiceId = soh.CarrierServiceId,
            CarrierServiceName = cs.ServiceName,
            CustomerPo = soh.CustomerPO,
            CustomerId = soh.CustomerId,
            CustomerName = cu.CustomerName,
            FieldSalesForceId = soh.FieldSalesForceId,
            RevisionNumber = soh.RevisionNumber,
            SalesForceId = soh.SalesForceId,
            LockId = soh.LockId,
            SalesOrderStatus = soh.SalesOrderStatus,
            SalesOrderStatusComputed = soh.SalesOrderStatusComputed,
            SalesOrderType = soh.SalesOrderType,
            SalesOrderTypeComputed = soh.SalesOrderTypeComputed
        };

var x = wms_SOHeaderResults.ToList();
```

Comment: Remove `new Customer()` and `new Data.CarrierService()` calls from your query - EF cannot convert that to sql.

Comment: @Evk. That worked. However .. I think the purpose of the new Customer and new Data.CarrierService() is to assign the default values of that selected customer and CarrierService to the result set. Is there perhaps another way of doing it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But in your select statement all you use from joined tables is `CarrierServiceName = cs.ServiceName` and `CustomerName = cu.CustomerName`, and they already will be null (`default(string`) if there is no match, so your default customer and carrierservice seems to not do anything useful anyway.